# Does $ \sum\left( (n^3+1)^{\frac{1}{3}} -n \right) $ converge or diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The test I know are Cauchy's root test, Cauchy's integral, Raabe's test, logarithmic test and D' Alembert's Ratio Test. I dont know which test I can use to prove that this series converges?
$$\sum \left( (n^3+1)^{\frac{1}{3}} -n \right) $$

Comment: I wanted to mark your question as a duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3396721/721644), but it has no accepted answers, so I couldn't.

Comment: Furthermore, [Find x for which $\sum [(n^3+1)^\frac{1}{3}-n]x^n$ converges.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1384240/721644).

Comment: Hint: use the mean value theorem on $f(x)=(n^3+x)^{1/3}$ on the interval $x\in[0,1]$.

Comment: [Convergence for the series: hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2502767/721644)

Comment: Also, [this closed question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1007348/721644)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we can prove that
$$
(n^3+1)^\frac13-n \leq \frac1{n^2},
$$
then we can use the comparison test to prove that the series converges.

Let's find $x$ such that
$$
(n^3+x)^\frac13-n \leq \frac1{n^2}.
$$
$$
\begin{align}
(n^3+x)^\frac13 &\leq \frac1{n^2}+n\\
n^3+x &\leq \left(\frac1{n^2}+n\right)^3\\
n^3+x &\leq n^3+3+\frac{3}{n^{3}}+\frac{1}{n^{6}}\\
x &\leq 3+\frac{3}{n^{3}}+\frac{1}{n^{6}}\\
& \leq 3.
\end{align}
$$
Since in your particular case $x=1\leq3$, we know that the sum is less than the sum of $1/n^2$, so it must converge.

Comment: There already exist five answered posts dealing with the same queation. 

Comment: @Croissant yeah, I just saw that after posting this. Oh well.

Comment: Seems that OP does not know about comparison test...

Comment: @IPPK I missed that. I just saw a few more obscure and complicated tests mentioned without reading carefully, so I assumed that OP knew the more simple and intuitive tests.

Comment: Heyy sorry i didn't see a duplicate of this question and I checked their answer out, but none made it as simple and straightforward as this one. Thank you so much seriously god bless, been looking everywhere for a simple answer